# `require': cannot load such file -- rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am running rspec and encountered the following error. I already looked for the similar posts but couldn't find the one that is relevant in this case.

`'require': cannot load such file -- rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter (LoadError)`

Ruby version: 2.4.3

Here is my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'rack-test', require: 'rack/test'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'timecop'
end
```

Here is the actual command:

```
/Users/<user_name>/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/<user_name>/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/rspec _3.7.1_ /Users/<user_name>/Desktop/github/test_rspec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter
```

test_rspec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'tests' do
  include_context 'scenario'

  # sample spec

end
```

Comment: Does `bundle exec rspec` have a different result?

Comment: Any update on this bug? Cause I got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, so:

- I removed my `Gemfile.lock`
- re run `bundle install`